# How to add SUM columns to a SQL query that are totaled by week?

Tags: sql, database, group-by, sum, calculated-columns

I'm writing a query to break down quantity of total transactions by week happening from 8pm to 3am. Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

| StoreNo | Week 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 000001 | 123 |
| 000002 | 123 |

(Week 2, Week 3,...)

I am also trying to pull from multiple tables, which are the following:

StoreNo: align_dim

Week No: time_day_dim

Transaction Count: tld.fact_v1

The query I have so far is:

```
SELECT a.restid,
COUNT(DISTINCT tld_fact_v1.dw_gc_header) as "Total Transactions"

FROM tbc.tbcdbv.tld_fact_v1
LEFT JOIN tbcdb.align_dim a ON a.dw_restid=tbc.tbcdbv.tld_fact_v1.dw_restid
LEFT JOIN tbcdbv.time_day_dim_v1 on tld_fact_v1.dw_day=time_day_dim_v1.dw_day

WHERE time_day_dim_v1.fiscalyearno = 'Y2022'

GROUP BY 1
```

This query works and I receive:

| StoreNo | Total |
| --- | --- |
| 000001 | 123 |
| 000002 | 123 |

How would I be able to get it split out by week?

Answer (score 0):

UNION the result of all count for year 2022

```
SELECT a.restid,
COUNT(DISTINCT tld_fact_v1.dw_gc_header) as "Total Transactions"
FROM tbc.tbcdbv.tld_fact_v1
LEFT JOIN tbcdb.align_dim a ON a.dw_restid=tbc.tbcdbv.tld_fact_v1.dw_restid
LEFT JOIN tbcdbv.time_day_dim_v1 on tld_fact_v1.dw_day=time_day_dim_v1.dw_day
WHERE time_day_dim_v1.fiscalyearno = 'Y2022'
GROUP BY 1
UNION
SELECT NULL,
COUNT(DISTINCT tld_fact_v1.dw_gc_header) as "Total Transactions"
FROM tbc.tbcdbv.tld_fact_v1
LEFT JOIN tbcdb.align_dim a ON a.dw_restid=tbc.tbcdbv.tld_fact_v1.dw_restid
LEFT JOIN tbcdbv.time_day_dim_v1 on tld_fact_v1.dw_day=time_day_dim_v1.dw_day
WHERE time_day_dim_v1.fiscalyearno = 'Y2022'
```

Comment: What if I want the sum of total transaction broken out by week instead of year?

Comment: theen remove from the second query the `WHERE` clause

Comment: Removing and keeping the clause gives out the same table.

Comment: you make a lot of LEFT JOINs, which means all rows of tld_fact_v1 are present in both queries that where clause will not change that, but ou didn_'t ask for that only how to add a row woith the total, which i explained, the faulty qzery was not my concern as you should have understand what you are programming, also in such cases helps to run the queries without the sggregatio to see whar result you get and if it is expected